# Getting attribute's value using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a python script which will extract the script locations after parsing from a webpage. 
Lets say there are two scenarios :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/something.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script>some JS</script>
```

I'm able to get the JS from the second scenario, that is when the JS is written within the  tags.

But is there any way, I could get the value of src from the first scenario (i.e extracting all the values of src tags within script such as http://example.com/something.js)

Here's my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r  = requests.get("http://rediff.com/")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for n in soup.find_all('script'):
    print n
```

**Output** : Some JS

**Output Needed** : http://example.com/something.js

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, please do accept the answer you are satistified with.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It will get all the `src` values only if they are present. Or else it would skip that `<script>` tag

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url="http://rediff.com/"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
sources=soup.findAll('script',{"src":True})
for source in sources:
 print source['src']
```

I am getting following two  `src` values as result

```
http://imworld.rediff.com/worldrediff/js_2_5/ws-global_hm_1.js
http://im.rediff.com/uim/common/realmedia_banner_1_5.js
```

I guess this is what you want. Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 5):

Get 'src' from script node.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r  = requests.get("http://rediff.com/")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for n in soup.find_all('script'):
    print "src:", n.get('src') <====
```

Comment: getting an output 'None'. 
src: None
src: None .. 
However if i do n.get('type') it shows me the result "text/javascript" 
Why is this issue with src?

Comment: Hmm..It should be working, I tried it in my system. What is the output of 'n'?

Comment: The output is 'None' .

Answer (score 1):

This should work, you just filter to find all the script tags, then determine if they have a 'src' attribute. If they do then the URL to the javascript is contained in the src attribute, otherwise we assume the javascript is in the tag

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Test HTML which has both cases
html = '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/something.js">'
html += '</script>  <script>some JS</script>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# Find all script tags 
for n in soup.find_all('script'):

    # Check if the src attribute exists, and if it does grab the source URL
    if 'src' in n.attrs:
        javascript = n['src']

    # Otherwise assume that the javascript is contained within the tags
    else:
        javascript = n.text

    print javascript
```

This output of this is

```
http://example.com/something.js
some JS
```