# Printing specific HTML values with Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, printing

I am having some trouble printing only a specific value of the scraped html

This the specific line of HTML my program scrapes for

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="MmghsMIlPm5bd2Dw"/>
```

My code is as follows

```
import requests, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, init


print(Fore.CYAN + "Lets begin!"")
init(autoreset=True)

url = raw_input("Enter URL: ")

print(Fore.CYAN + "\nGetting form key")


r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

data = soup.find_all("input", {'name': 'form_key', 'type':'hidden'})

for data in data:
    print(Fore.YELLOW + "Found Form Key:")
    print(data)
```

The program scrapes it fine, but prints the entire line where I desire to only print "MmghsMIlPm5bd2Dw" (no quotes)

How can I achieve this??

I have tried things like

```
print soup.find(data).text
```

And

```
last_input_tag = soup.find("input", id="value")
print(last_input_tag)
```

But nothing has seemed to really work

Comment: This answer covers your question (I think): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733023/getting-attributes-value-using-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you print data and it shows you the whole input statement you should be able to print the value by specifying it

```
print(data.get('value'))
```

Please refere to documentation here
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: @cbos93 if an answer is correct, you should upvote it and accept it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

More generically... presuming that there are multiple tags in the html:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<title><p><input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="MmghsMIlPm5bd2Dw"/>
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="abcdefghijklmo"/>
<input name="form_key" type="hidden"/>
</p></title>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

We can search for all tags with the name `input`.

```
tags = soup.find_all('input')
```

We can then cycle through all the tags to retrieve those tags with `value` attributes. Because tags can be treated much like dictionaries under the hood, we can query for the attributes as though they were keys, using the `*.get()` method. This method looks for an attribute called `value`:

- If it finds this attribute, the method returns the value associated with
  the attribute
- If it cannot find the attribute, the `*.get()` method
  will return the default value you provide as a second argument:

To cycle through the tags...

```
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('value', 'value attribute not found'))

=== Output: ===
MmghsMIlPm5bd2Dw
abcdefghijklmo
value attribute not found
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I like how short this is! It works fine but in the out put, it prints the value I need but also throws an. "KeyError: 'value'"

What would be the cause of this?

Comment: Presuming you have multiple tags, if one or more fails to have a 'value' attribute, then you will get a KeyError. I will edit the answer to account for that.